# 3-pole LC filter design

Tags: filter, low-pass, frequency-response

When designing a 3-pole LC filter with a ferrite bead as inductor L, using capacitor values intended for a LC filter with an inductor (not a ferrite) produces a large 'dip' or 'bounce' in its frequency response.

In a previous question, people have said that the 'dip' is due to the internal resonance of the bead. However, by changing the capacitor values from 680 uF to 15 uF (bead inductance is 14 uF) this eliminates the resonance entirely, producing a smooth response.

Should I use capacitor values designated for a LC filter with an inductor(not ferrite, 680 uF for a ~1 kHz cutoff) or capacitor values closest to the inductance of the bead (15 uF, closest E series value) to eliminate the 'dip'? I am inclined to use the bottom arrangement(picture 2), however I want to hear some feedback first.

This filter is intended for use on the *output* of a SMPS (LRS-50-24) to filter out HF noise which the LDO (a LM1084) cannot attenuate. Ferrite bead is a WE 7427503-UKL, capacitors are standard aluminium electrolytics.

[image: Bead equivalent circuit]

[image: Simulation 1, 680uF capacitors]

[image: Simulation 2, 15uF capacitors]

Comment: Please show capacitor ESR and ESL, and source resistance.

Comment: ESR-about 0.07 ohms 
ESL-about 9nH, capacitor is quite small.
I do not know the source resistance, signal 'source' is a voltage source('voltage' in LTspice).

Comment: Bead inductance is 14 uF ?

Comment: State the impedance of the signal source and provide an equivalent circuit of the ferrite bead (L, C, Resr, Rparallel). Please explain why you believe a 3rd order filter is appropriate and needed. Using electrolytic capacitors for filters is often a bad idea.

Comment: As stated in my question, a 3rd order filter is needed to eliminate HF noise from the SMPS, which will pass straight through the LDO regulator(LM1084, see Ripple Rejection graph). Would reducing the bead inductance mean smaller ceramic capacitors could be used?

Comment: Please specify what emission level (output ripple, differential mode) your SMPS produces, and what emission level your final load requires.

Comment: @TimWilliams I do not have physical access to the SMPS in question. From the datasheet, the LRS-50-24 is specified at 150mV p-p of ripple, output ground is floating and is not connected to mains earth.

Comment: If you don't know what level of ripple or noise the load should have, I would just as well recommend leaving it alone until problems are discovered; you can always wire a filter inline later if need be.